# How Chain Multiple Methods in AngularJs after data is returned

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I would like to know what the best way is to call or chain my methods AFTER my data has been returned.**

The way I see it (and I might be completely wrong, hence I am asking the question!), is that the "heavy lifting"/"long wait" of fetching the data is done, and one could then call the various methods `asynchronously`, appose to having the methods do the work `synchronously`.

*Am I wrong?*

**Here is an example of the method I use to handle my returned data:**

```
function formatDataAccordingToLocation(data) {
    if (mediaSourceGraphChange) {
        mediaSourceGraphConfig();
        populateMediaSourceData(data.channels_data);
        mediaSourceGraphChange = false;
    }
    else if (sentimentGraphChange) {
        sentimentGraphConfig();
        populateSentimentData(data);
        sentimentGraphChange = false;
    }
    else if (hashtagsGraphChange) {
        hashtagsGraphConfig();
        populateHashtagsData(data);
        hashtagsGraphChange = false;
    }
    else {
        $scope.totalMentions = data.mentions_count;
        populateSummaryData(data);
        volumeGraphConfig();
        populateVolumeData(data.timeline_data, data.time_trend);
        populateHashtagsData(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need callbacks for this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Declaring_and_Using_Callbacks

Comment: Hi. Nope, no callbacks needed. Each function uses the returned data to modify my view and $scope. It is simple functions, assigning data etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The way I see it (and I might be completely wrong, hence I am asking
>   the question!), is that the "heavy lifting"/"long wait" of fetching
>   the data is done, and one could then call the various methods
>   asynchronously, appose to having the methods do the work
>   synchronously.

For example here :

```
 if (mediaSourceGraphChange) {
        mediaSourceGraphConfig();
        populateMediaSourceData(data.channels_data);
        mediaSourceGraphChange = false;
    }
```

If not dependencies between functions as @Tom Johnson said, I think another good  good reason to call `mediaSourceGraphConfig()` or `populateMediaSourceData()` in an asynchronously way would be if these methods may take a some elapsed time to return and that you don't want to block the browser/user during this elapsed time.

Comment: Thank you - it makes sense. :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the angular $q service in your methods, to use this you can;

```
var mediaSourceGraphConfig = function(){
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     //logic
     return deferred.resolve();
}
```

For each function you want to call asynchronously, and then in your master function you can;

```
function formatDataAccordingToLocation(data) {
    mediaSourceGraphConfig().then(populateMediaSourceData(variable));
}
```

You can also use deferred.reject if your function returns the wrong data.

More information on $q [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response and help. The thing is; my data has already returned using $q. My question is regarding the modification of the returned data, and whether it is then necessary to use $q and method chaining etc. Or can I simple call one function after the other as per my example?

Comment: I understand, it depends on whether the functions depend on each other, so if function 2 requires any response or alteration made in function 1, then I would recommend chaining them - especially if they're making http requests because angular likes to move from function to function while leaving pending http requests open. Otherwise if the functions are independent of each other, then your way would work just fine.

Comment: The functions don't depend on each other to return any values or data. Thanks for the help!